# C# Date Parse Exact mindate issues

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following function

```
DateTime fromDateParam = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(DateTime.MinValue),"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",null);
```

It says input string not recognised as a valid date.

Any ideas how I can get any the min date recognised to parse exact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you're converting the original time to a string using the *default* formatting, but then you're specifying *custom* formatting for the parsing.

If you specify a format string using `DateTime.ToString(format)` and keep the format consistent, it works fine:

```
string formatString = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string text = DateTime.MinValue.ToString(formatString);
Console.WriteLine(text);
DateTime fromDateParam = DateTime.ParseExact(text, formatString, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In other words (continuing Skeet's answer), `Convert.ToString(DateTime.MinValue)` is based on current/default CultureInfo, etc.