# .NET DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing

When trying to use the parse method on the `DateTime` class, I get an exception thrown:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

- The string reads as `"26/10/2009 8:47:39 AM"` when outputted.
- This string is obtained from a group on a match from a regex.
- None of the strings obtained from this match group will parse to datetime.

Examples of other strings:

```
26/10/2009 8:47:39 AM
26/10/2009 8:00:41 AM
26/10/2009 7:48:35 AM
```

The weird thing is, I am sure it has worked before.

Comment: Is your locale settings in windows set properly?

Comment: Yeh but the application was being run as a service, and the profile of the user running the service did not. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) takes regional settings (culture of current thread) into account. Therefore, I'd use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx) and specify the correct format explicitly with an invariant culture (or the culture you need, eg. `en-US`, for AM/PM).

Answer (score 25):

Parsing strings into `DateTime` object is almost always a pain. If you know for certain that they will always have the format as your examples do, this should work:

```
string input = "26/10/2009 8:00:41 AM";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I was writing this exact same answer.

Comment: Although I was going to add some information about the regional settings (globalization) that affect date parsing.

Comment: @Vinko: so did I. It's the pain part. ;) No, seriously, it is a rather complex area that is a common problem source. I did write a sort of lengty answer on the topic a while ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437454/date-format-problem

Comment: @FredrikMörk i´m using this solution, the strings input is correctly formated but my datetime variable is setting to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, i´m using it in .Net 4.5, do you have any idea dude?

Comment: @Guillelon what does your input string and format string look like?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using the wrong culture. The month cannot be 26, so it's not a US timestamp. This works though:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("26/10/2009 8:47:39 AM",
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Has the culure changed on the machine? 26/10/2009 is a good UK date but a bad US date (for instance)

Comment: That had actually just occurred to me.
Datetime.parse seems to have an overload for the cultural time format. Just trying to find out how to use it now :)

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Either call DateTime.Parse() with the culture as a parameter or call DateTime.ParseExact() with the date, the exact format of the date to parse, and the culture:

[DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I second @Lucero, `Parse` uses current thread's culture info etc. See also the opposite direction: a `ToString` [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437078/c-date-parse-exact-mindate-issues) in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve some really strange date format coming from other system... In this example is for SPANISH format ...

```
string input="07/06/2019 07:01:54 p. m.";


public static DateTime ParseSpanishDate(string input)
{
    string normalized = input.Replace("a. m.", "AM").Replace("p. m.", "PM");
    normalized = normalized.Replace("12:00:00 AM", "00:00:00 AM");
    return  DateTime.Parse(normalized, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es"));
}
```

Comment: When you have a new question, then please ask a new question. This space is reserved for answers only - most people will not see your question.

Comment: sorry, I just put a solution that worked for me with spanish dates.