# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when converting to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string to DateTime and then insert it to sql.
In my local computer all works fine, but on the server the application throws an exception:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

**I use Textboxs to create a datetime object like this:**

[image]

I'm using this line to build the date:

```
start = startEventTB.Text + " " + ShourDD.SelectedValue + ":" + SminuteDD.SelectedValue;
        end = endEventTB.Text + " " + EhourDD.SelectedValue + ":" + EminuteDD.SelectedValue;
```

and then convert it

**This is the code after the button click:**

```
 act_event add_event = new act_event();
        string start, end;
        DateTime strt_date = new DateTime();
        DateTime end_date = new DateTime();

        add_event.name = name_event.Text;

        start = startEventTB.Text + " " + ShourDD.SelectedValue + ":" + SminuteDD.SelectedValue;
        end = endEventTB.Text + " " + EhourDD.SelectedValue + ":" + EminuteDD.SelectedValue;

        strt_date = Convert.ToDateTime(start); //This is the line that throws the error
        add_event.start = strt_date;



        end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(end);
        add_event.end = end_date;

        add_event.description = des_event.Text;

        add_event.address = loc_event.Text;


        db.add_event(add_event);
```

**Then I get this:**

[image]

Comment: And this is why you use date pickers instead of text...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having most likely links to formatting issues.  Since DateTime has a lot of different ways it can be formatted, the `Convert.ToDateTime( ... )` is probably using a format that is different from your `hour\minute` format.

Try using `DateTime.Parse` \ `DateTime.TryParse` \ `DateTime.ParseExact`

See:

- [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx)
- [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)
- [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)
- [.NET DateTime.Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870589/net-datetime-parse)
- [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for formatting strings

Comment: I just can't convert the datepicker text to Datetime, no matter if I use ConvertTo, Parse, ParseExact. it just throws error. That's annoying : \

Comment: What is the string text from the datepicker?

Comment: You can see it in the picture above

Comment: The string `31/07/2013` is parsed by `DateTime sample = DateTime.ParseExact("31/07/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);` on my environment

Comment: `DateTime sample = DateTime.ParseExact("31/07/2013 8:15", "dd/MM/yyyy h:m", null);` also works

Answer (score 0):

1. It's probably a formatting\localization issue, different machines may be set to different locales and expect the dates to written differently.
2. I think you're getting yourself into unneeded trouble. Why create the string in the first place only to parse it later? Wouldn't it be easier to do something like -

   date = new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, HH, MM, SS);

with the data from the controls?

Comment: I just can't convert the datepicker text to Datetime, no matter if I use ConvertTo, Parse, ParseExact. it just throws error. That's annoying : \